# Is it a good practice to call setState or other methods on this.props.children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my understanding, **props** are meant to be set by parent, and **state** is meant to be private to component.

> this.state is private to the component and can be changed by calling this.setState(). When the state is updated, the component re-renders itself.

Parent component should **not** call `setState` on its children, ever. Is this correct?

Imagine parent `<Form>` has some validation mechanism on submitting, and wants to pass all `<FormInput>`s validation errors. **Should it do this via props, or can it call `setState` on its children?**

Finally, is it a good practice to call *anything* on child components?

Consider this method:

```
validate: function () {
  var hasError = false;

  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
    if (child.validate) {
      hasError = hasError || child.validate();
    }
  });

  return !hasError;
}
```

It works, but **I'm not sure duck-typing children methods is the way to go in React**.
What do you think?

Comment: You should update the child props, not their state. But I don’t see how you want to do that in your code, it looks like you are collecting `valid` states from your child components, no?

Comment: @David: This code calls `validate()` on each child that has such method. Again, I don't think it's a good approach, but I can't articulate why.

Comment: Ok... but what is your question about? The title doesn’t match your code example.

Comment: @David: There are two questions that are closely related. I edited the title and added emphasis.

Comment: I don’t see the similarity between calling a child method and setting it’s state, except that `setState` is also a method. But handling states is a completely different thing than just calling a custom method.

Comment: @David: My question is whether it's OK for parents to somehow interact with `props.children` given to them, or if this is a bad practice, and the [one-way data flow approach](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html) is better (which I think it the case, but I'm not quite sure).

Comment: @Dan There are cases where a component wants to edit `props.children`, but it shouldn't modify them directly. In that case you should clone the children and modify the props of the cloned component. The feature was exposed in 0.9.0 and is documented here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really a good idea.

With validation example, although it would work if your form had a few direct children components, what if you want to validate fields inside a `<div>` as well? They won't be immediate children, so now your logic constrains your markup.

One way to accomplish what you want is to **give children exactly the level of control over parent's state they need by giving a special object**. React has a built-in example of this: [`ReactLink` and `LinkedStateMixin`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

You can take the same idea and apply it to validation.

Answer (score 0):

Every component in react is independent and each component should maintain their own state not the others. They can only send props to other components and its the other component decision to update its state or not. so its a better practice to send props to the children instead of calling `setState` of them.

However according to your question in case of form validation if a form is submitted and the form is invalid the the form triggers Invalid event on each of its input field.

So you can write functions to handle the invalid event on every child due to which you also don't have to pass props from parent to child.

Comment: Are you intending to quote from somewhere? The answer is formatted as a quote.